# ASP on IIS 7:: HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error

Tags: asp-classic

So far I have the experience of deploying php applications only. For the first time I tried working on a asp with MSSQL but with the trail page only(just a snapshot of the overall data from one table), i am getting 500 server error. These are the steps I followed during IIS deployment
Copied the folder (asp output) to root directory
As i am using local system (windows 7 prof) I used "All Unassigned" with a new port (81) on site binding {80 being already used by php site}
Went to my browser and entered "localhost:81/index.htm", which in turn is directing to the required asp page but instead of table containing data i am getting "HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error"

Can some one kindly help? I am sure that i am missing some basic setup in IIS but not sure what.

Many thanks
Yuvraj

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific about how you set it up?  For example, when creating a new 'web site' in IIS you need to:

1. Create a local to be the root of your website.  In this case I am creating a website called 'mysamplesite' and am placing the root directory in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysamplesite.

[image]

I am placing a file in it called index.htm with the following contents:

[image]

2. Now in inetmgr (IIS manager) I right click on sites and select 'Add Web sSite...'

[image]

3. In the Add Web Site dialog I type the name of the application.  In this case MySampleSite.  As I type that in, IIS is also filling in the name of the application pool. I also enter the path to the root directory (c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysamplesite) and set the port to 81.  Everything else I leave alone.

[image]

Since index.htm is already in my list of documents, the site comes up when I browse it.

[image]

Does your eventvwr show anything?

Comment: Wow this is prompt, thanks Alex. Yes I have created a local directory, created a new website in IIS (binding port 81) pointing to the root directory.For the Application Pool bit, I have created a new one with v4.0 .net framework, Pipeline mode classic, and identity as ApplicationPoolIdentity. Still no luck with the Server error. As a matter of fact the localhost:81/index.htm is directing the page to menu.asp, that is when i am getting the 500 server error

Comment: There is another option for default document.  Have you checked that to see if index.htm is listed there?  If that is going to be the page you want to land on event at the root, check that and move it to the top of the list.

Comment: Yes, index.htm is on the top of the list on default document page? Do i need to set up anything special for ASP (taking the reference of PHP, you need to add php component thru php manager etc etc)..

Comment: You shouldn't need to setup anything special.  What's in the index.htm file?

Comment: Sometimes you can get this too if your application pool settings are off.  Are you browsing this from your local machine?  the 500 error should be more detailed there.

Comment: Till date iam not able to solve this problem, still being badly hunted with server 500 1.1 error. Just to check if asp pages are loaded or not, i created a simple asp page to display current date and time, and dumped it in root folder, this is absolute working well. However my asp page which connects to MSSQL database for login is producing server 500 error. I have disabled the "friedly error" in IE, also in the IIS i have set the option for detailed errors, but not  getting any fruitful information. Please note that php pages are working well on same IIS. Please help.